# Feeding neural network matrix data as input

Tags: matrix, input, neural-network

I have a use case for neural networks that must take multiple matrices as input and produce multiple matrices as output. This situation arises from chemistry. The important fact here is that the matrix expresses adjacency information so the structure needs to be maintained somehow.

Normally, for XOR etc., you feed one value to each input neuron. How would you collapse the matrix to feed it in while maintaining the matrix structure?

Answer (score 2):

To maintain adjacency information you should use a convolutional neural network (CNN). See [this article](http://machinelearningmastery.com/crash-course-convolutional-neural-networks/]) for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Have as many input neurons as the total number of elements in all your input matrices.  So if you have **m** input matrices with **n** elements each, just have **m X n** neurons. The same goes for output neurons. Have as many output neurons as your output total matrices' elements. As long as there are patterns in your data, the network can be expected to recognize them with sufficient amount of training. Even if your input and output are not clearly structured as you want it to be.